# "Access denied for user ''@'172.18.0.1' (using password: NO)"

Tags: mysql, .net, docker

Estoy utilizando docker, Mysql, .net y una arquitectura con microservicios.
Cuando corro los microservicios no tengo problemas, pero cuando hago un request a un microservicio este devuelve el mensaje "Access denied for user ''@'172.18.0.1' (using password: NO)". Es raro porque solo me pasa con un microservicio. Mi cadena de conexion esta bien escrita (mi root y contraseña son correctos)

Comment: Claramente está usando un usuario y contraseña vacios ''. Podrías mostrar algo de código o configuración?

Answer (score 0):

Es muy seguro que lo que está haciendo es intentar conectar directamente al contenedor y este se encuentra en otra red. Debe colocar el contenedor en la red bridge y exponer el puerto al que se quiere conectar.